# What does ショッショ mean?

Tags: onomatopoeia

そいじゃ、あいこのショッショで……

They're playing the game and it's a tie

Comment: It would help you if you improved the quality of your question.  Examples of how you could improve this are: what's the context?  Where did you find this?  What do you think it means (ie., what have you managed to figure out on your own so far)?  Right now, it just comes across as rather brash and like you've not made any effort on your own.

Comment: 日本語では「じゃんけん **ポン!** 」「あいこで **ショ！** 」とか言いますけど、英語では rock, paper, scissors, **go!** とか rock, paper, scissors, **shoot!** みたいな言い方はしないんでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そいじゃ、あいこのショッショで……　＝　それでは、「あいこのショッ」でもう一度やりましょう。＝Then, let's do it again (with the re-starting call)

「あいこのショッ（ショ）」は「じゃんけん」の掛け声の一つで、もう一度じゃんけんをするときの掛け声です。"Aiko no/de sho" is the re-starting call of "Rock-paper-scissors."

じゃんけんは、「じゃんけんぽん」または「最初はグー、じゃんけんぽん」という掛け声を言って始めます。We start "rock-paper-scissors" with the starting call, "rock, paper, scissors!" or "one-two-three!"

「あいこ」はその時のじゃんけんで勝敗が決まらなかった事を意味します。”Aiko" means that the result was a tie.

その場合に、じゃんけんをやり直しますが、その時の掛け声が、「あいこでしょ」なのです。In that case, we do it again with the re-starting call, "aiko de sho" (It's a tie. Okay, let's do it again, one-two-three!")

Therefore, そいじゃ、あいこでしょっしょ means "okay, let's do it again, now!"

Hope this helps.